# Error on setting custom ListView Image

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to set a custom `ListView` with `ArrayAdapter`. Every `ListItem` has an `ImageView` and two `TextViews`.

The layout of each Item `rowlayout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/item_subTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:text="Titel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_subTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Untertitel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I set the `ListView` in my Badges Activity:

```
public class Badges extends ActionBarActivity{

List<Badge> myBadges = new ArrayList<Badge>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.badges_layout);

    populateBadgeList();
    populateListView();

}

private void populateBadgeList() {
    myBadges.add(new Badge("Some Text", "Some further Text", R.drawable.badge1));
    //and so on
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Badge> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Badge> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(Badges.this, R.layout.rowlayout, myBadges);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        }

        Badge currentBadge = myBadges.get(position);

        ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        //the error is on the following line:
        itemIcon.setImageResource(currentBadge.getIconID());

        TextView itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        itemTitle.setText(currentBadge.getTitle());

        TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
        itemSubtitle.setText(currentBadge.getSubtitle());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Here is the Badge class:

```
public class Badge {
String title;
String subtitle;
int iconID;

public Badge(String title, String subtitle, int iconID) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.iconID = iconID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public int getIconID() {
    return iconID;
}
```

}

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
```

I marked the line at which the error occurs in the code. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
TextView itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
```

Use

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
TextView itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
```

this with

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
```

and similarly

```
TextView itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
```

with

```
TextView itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

the view you just inflate didn't add to your activity's layout. So with the activity method

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
itemIcon.setImageResource(currentBadge.getIconID());
```

You couldn't find the view with the specific id. Instead, you should use

```
ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
itemIcon.setImageResource(currentBadge.getIconID());
```

It will work properly. Other views are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line: ArrayAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();

Change to this: MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();

Also, put item view in front of findViewById methods (ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_icon); )

I would actually recommend generalising your adapter class, so that you could pass any resource (row layout) and list to it :) (However, it is not necessary for the app to work.)

So something like this:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Badge> {

   int resource;
   public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Badge> items) {
       super(context, resource, items);
       this.resource = resource;
   }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View itemView = convertView;
    if(itemView == null) {
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }

    Badge currentBadge = getItem(position);

    ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    //the error is on the following line:
    itemIcon.setImageResource(currentBadge.getIconID());

    TextView itemTitle = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    itemTitle.setText(currentBadge.getTitle());

    TextView itemSubtitle = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_subTitle);
    itemSubtitle.setText(currentBadge.getSubtitle());

    return itemView;
   }
}
```